# Do you ever need correlation-id when using RabbitMQs Direct Reply-To?

Tags: rabbitmq

Everything I've been able to find through Google says that because of Direct Reply-To correlation-id is no longer necessary to correlate a specific request with a specific response.

But to me it looks like you clearly still need to do it if there's a possibility of multiple concurrent RPC calls. In such a scenario since you're only consuming from the single direct reply-to pseudoqueue, there's no way to tell which RPC call the reaponse is arriving from without a correlation-id.

Is my assumption correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you're right.

When multiple in-flight reply messages are directed to the same "address" (i.e. queue), you need something to tell them apart. `reply-to` is "address to reply to" [1]; reasonable options include setting `correlation-id` ("application correlation identifier" [1]) on both the request and response messages, or setting a distinct `message-id` [1] on every message and mentioning a request's `message-id` in the `correlation-id` of the response.

[1]: Useful reference: section 1.8.1 (page 42) of [the RabbitMQ annotated AMQP 0-91 detailed protocol specification](https://www.rabbitmq.com/resources/specs/amqp-xml-doc0-9-1.pdf).